# ui router is rendering the surrounding html content

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple configuration that is not working. The ui view is not rendering the template.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
</ul>

<div ui-view></div>

<script src="/src/client/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/src/client/app/config.js"></script>
```

AppJS

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('barmehealth', ['ui.router'])
  .controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope) {

  });
}());
```

ConfigJS

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var core = angular.module('barmehealth');

  core.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider
    .state('register', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: '/views/register.html',
     controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    });
  });
}());
```

When I go to the route by clicking on the link to register, the ui view renders the entire html page with the view tag and not the template which is given in the state.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/brm99i3thsw30h6/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-29%20at%209.15.14%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: Two things: 1. what's the content of `register.html`? 2. can you check if the browser is actually loading it?

Comment: Its simply div with the word register and it is not loading it at all.

Comment: So the problem is probably the app is loading `index.html` instead of `register.html` (that's why you see the _surrounding html_). Try fixing the `templateUrl`. I think removing the first slash should be enough (`views/register.html`).

Comment: I just posted what I found as you were adding this. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the path wrong in the templateUrl. It should have been

templateUrl: '/app/views/register.html'

Does anyone know if it is a default behavior for the view tag to load the surrounding html?